# KeyValuePair with generic values

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to create a list this way?

```
List<string,KeyValuePair<string,T>> lst;
```

Comment: Are you able to explain what you are trying to do, or the data that you'd like to store in this object? The 'list' that you've described isn't a list, is illegal, and doesn't make sense.

Comment: The signature of a List is `List<T>`. This mean you can provide only one type between the bracket. What definition would you expect from the example you gave ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) accepts only one generic argument, so you cannot specify *both* `string` *and* `KeyValuePair<string, T>`. As pointed out, maybe you mean a [`Dictionary<K, V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Generally, your code with the `T` argument is only possible if it appears within a generic method or class that itself accepts a type argument named `T`.

If you expect to be able to store different elements (i.e. various types for `T`) in your list; that is not possible. Imagine, if every item had a different `T`, what advantage would typing to `T` make in the first place? You couldn't make any assumptions about the values as their type would be unknown. Therefore, all you can do is specify the most specific common base type of all types that your values can possibly belong to - possibly `System.Object`, if they really don't share any other common traits.

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Lopierdis: Could you please select the answer as accepted then, or is that not possible any more now that the question has been closed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, T>> lst;
```

Comment: Judging from the title, the question seems to be about the generic type argument, not about list classes.